# Number of unbroken supersymmetries in compactifications

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification

In type II compactifications, we take a 10/11-d spinor $\epsilon$ to decompose into internal $\eta$ and external $\zeta$ pieces, $$\epsilon^1=\zeta^1\otimes\eta^1\ \ (+c.c.)$$ $$\epsilon^2=\zeta^2\otimes\eta^2\ \ (+c.c.)$$

From page 424 of [Witten 1981](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321381900213),

> Each solution of $\nabla\epsilon=0$ in the internal space would correspond to an unbroken supersymmetry charge in four dimensions.

I take this to mean that the number of $\eta$'s gives $\mathcal{N}$, the number of spacetime supersymmetries. For instance, if we take $\eta^1=\eta^2\equiv\eta$ above, then we have only one covariantly constant internal spinor, and so $\mathcal{N}=1$.

On the other hand, from [Grana 2005](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0509003.pdf) page 9:

> When there is one covariantly constant internal spinor [i.e. if we take $\eta^1=\eta^2\equiv\eta$], the internal gravitino equation tells
> us that there are two four-dimensional supersymmetry parameters, $\zeta^{1,2}$. This compactification preserves therefore eight supercharges, i.e. $\mathcal{N}=2$ in four dimensions.

These two statements seem at odds with each other so I'm assuming I'm missing something -- is it the number of $\eta$'s or that of $\zeta$'s that determines the unbroken SUSY's in 4d?

Comment: Is it not as 'simple' as the fact that Witten is discussing $N = 1$ 11D supergravity, for which there is only one spinor, i.e. there is only one $\varepsilon$, while the second paper is discussing 10D IIA/IIB for which there are 2 = II supersymmetries $\varepsilon^{1,2}$, i.e. two different cases.